Why can I not change var property in SwiftUI Struct?
I am new to learning swift and swiftui. I have written code which has the error

Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Here is the code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var tapCount = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap Count: \(tapCount)") {
            self.incrementCount()
        
        }
    }

    mutating func incrementCount() {
        self.tapCount += 1
    }
}

I don't understand why I cannot change the value of tapCount

Mutating doesn’t work with a SwiftUI view, you need to use property wrappers https://developer.apple.com/pathways/swiftui/ never access View properties or functions from a parent.

to understand why you cannot change the value of tapCount you need to learn and understand the very basics of SwiftUI and Swift, like value types in Swift. There is no short cut. Look also into using SwiftUI State for this example.

Related post

To really understand why you cannot change the value of tapCount, you'll need to do a bit of reading and gain a solid grasp on a number of Swift fundamentals, like value vs reference types, structs vs classes or this article on the same topic.
But, if you want to learn how it is done, rather than why it is done so, just know that in your code tapCount should be a @State and the increment function non-mutating. For some reading: Managing user interface state
Like this:
struct IncrementButton: View {
    
    @State private var tapCount = 0
        
        var body: some View {
            Button("Tap Count: \(tapCount)") {
                self.incrementCount()
            }
        }
        
        private func incrementCount() {
            self.tapCount += 1
        }
}
#Preview {
    IncrementButton()
}


Uhm... my answer was heavily edited by @malhalwith a completely different approach. While the new approach may work, it was not at all the point of my answer. As a matter of fact, this could have been an answer in itself, as an alternative way to solve the original issue or maybe with an explanation as to how it's different or maybe even better. As it stands, not even I know the point of it. Not cool.

Can you not rollback the edit (I don't think rolling back has a reputation requirement)? In any case, I have rolled back the edit for you.

@Sweeper Thanks, it's the first time I came across something like this and wanted to see if it was an acceptable practice. Also, I wasn't sure if it was done by a moderator or else.

No problem. Edits that go against the intent of the author are not acceptable. A moderator would have a diamond and the word "Mod" next to their name.
